# Execution Flow for Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using Executor Service for multithreading. I have the below code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
final Multimap<String, String> queueIds = ArrayListMultimap.create();

for (final String sId : sMultiMap.keySet()) {
    for (final String gL : gsList) {
        for (final String sL : ssList) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(sId);
                    JSONArray guList = null;
                    JSONArray coJsonArray;
                    JSONObject arrayGuidObject, coResults = null;
                    String skillSetParam;
                    String url;
                    int result_count;
                    Long queue_id;
                    skillSetParam = "parameters";
                    url = " here is the url";
                    try {
                        URL urlEncoded = new URL(url);
                        URI uri = new URI(urlEncoded.getProtocol(), urlEncoded.getUserInfo(),
                                urlEncoded.getHost(), urlEncoded.getPort(), urlEncoded.getPath(),
                                urlEncoded.getQuery(), urlEncoded.getRef());
                        urlEncoded = uri.toURL();

                        guList = // get a list from API

                        for (int i = 0; i < guList.length(); i++) {
                            arrayGuidObject = guList.optJSONObject(i);

                            if (arrayGuidObject != null) {
                                System.out.println("Here 1");
                            }
                        }
                        coJsonArray = coResults.getJSONArray("results");
                        if (coResults != null) {
                            result_count = coResults.getInt("resultcount");
                            if (result_count > 0) {
                                for (int k = 0; k <= coJsonArray.length() ; k++) {
                                    JSONObject j = coJsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                                    queue_id = j.getLong("id");
                                    queueIds.put(sId + "-" + gL + "-" + sL,
                                            "\"" + Long.toString(queue_id) + "\"");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        int size = queueIds.keySet().size();
                        int flag = 0;
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("folderPath"
                                        + sId + "-" + gL + "-"
                                        + sL.replace(" ", "").replaceAll("/", "_") + ".json"),
                                        "utf-8"));
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Entered here");
                            for (String sGS : queueIds.keySet()) {
                                if (flag == 0) {
                                    writer.write("{");
                                }
                                flag++;
                                if (flag == size) {
                                    writer.write("\"" + sGS + "\"" + ": "
                                            + queueIds.get(sGS).toString());
                                } else {
                                    writer.write("\"" + sGS + "\"" + ": "
                                            + queueIds.get(sGS).toString() + ",");
                                }

                                if (flag == size) {
                                    writer.write("}");
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Done");
                        } finally {
                            writer.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    queueIds.clear();
                }
            });

            System.out.println("queueIds " + queueIds);

        }
    }
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(24L, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So here i am not able to find the correct execution flow. When i run the program, it prints the empty queueIds First, which is after the execute. So my intention here is to open 100 threads at a time which loops through 100 values of the loop and i want to see the line by line execution here. I want to see sID which i am printing in the first line after the execute. Can anyone please suggest the flow of execution.

Comment: If you want to do anything after the completion of the threads, do after `awaitTermination`.

Comment: @Chinmayjain I am not trying to do it after the threads. I want to open 100 threads and process the loop faster and i want to execute the run method line by line. When i print it the first thing is it prints queueIds 100 times . But why its not printing the sId which is the first line in run method.

Comment: Because you are trying to print queueIds just after the executor. So what it is doing is **it opens a new executor in each loop, and prints the queueIds**. All the processing in the executor will be done afterwards, asynchronously. Move queueIds after `awaitTermination`.